# Are sub-properties with object values copied by reference in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following code:

```
 A={
  prop1: 12,
  prop2: {x:12}
 };
 newprop2={k:55,l:3};
 A.prop2=newprop2;
 newprop2 = {m:65, n:25};
 console.log(A);
```

Output is:

```
  { prop1: 12, prop2: { k: 55, l: 3 } }
```

I expected the output to be:

```
  { prop1: 12, prop2: {m:65, n:25} }
```

Because objects are copied by reference, I was hoping that sub-properties were copied by reference because the objects I want to assign as values are LARGE and do not want to maintain multiple copies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, objects are copied by reference. But at the line `newprop2 = {m:65, n:25};` you are assigning a new object to the `newprop2`. The older reference is still assigned to the `A.prop2` and it refers to the old object to which `newprop2` was referring. So `newprop2` now refers to another object which is already has nothing with the object to which it was refering before.

In concise, you have changed the reference of the `newprop2`. If you will access properties via `newprop2`, not change the reference, you will mutate the same object to which `A.prop2` refers.

```js
const A = {
  prop1: 12,
  prop2: { x: 12 }
};

let newprop2 = { k:55, l:3 };
A.prop2 = newprop2;

newprop2.k = 65;
newprop2.l = 25;

console.log(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because it was referenced by `newprop2={k:55,l:3};` . later on you had changed reference of `newprop2` but it was after assignment was done , so `prop2 of A` has older refrence of `newprop2` . at the end `A.prop2 !== newprop2` .you have to set value to property `prop2` once you assigned new value to  `newprop2`. So just assign `prop2` values after new assignment of `prop2`.

```js
 A={
  prop1: 12,
  prop2: {x:12}
 };
 newprop2={k:55,l:3};
 newprop2 = {m:65, n:25};
  A.prop2=newprop2;
 console.log(A);
```

Now `A.prop2 === newprop2` .